# Changing "Contents" name in revtex4-1

Tags: table-of-contents, naming, revtex

I need to change the way "Contents" appears in `\tableofcontents` in a revtex4-1 document.

Other answers indicate `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{changes!}`, however when I uncomment any of those in

```
\documentclass[]{revtex4-1}

\def\title{A title}
\def\author{Me}

%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{T\lowercase{able of} C\lowercase{ontents}}
%\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{L\lowercase{ist of} F\lowercase{igures}}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{T\lowercase{able of} C\lowercase{ontents}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage

\section*{A\lowercase{cknowledgments}}
none!
\newpage

\section*{A\lowercase{bstract}}
\begin{center}
{``\title''}\\
\end{center}
\vspace{.3cm}
Some text.
\newpage

\setlength{\baselineskip}{12pt}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\setlength{\baselineskip}{20pt}

\makeatletter
\let\toc@pre\relax
\let\toc@post\relax
\makeatother 

\listoffigures
\newpage

\listoftables
\clearpage

\section{\label{sec_defs}D\lowercase{efinitions}}
\end{document}
```

I get "Latex Error: \contentsname undefined" (or similar for `\listfigurename`).

Help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `revtex4-1` class uses the non-standard macros `\tocname`, `\lofname`, and `\lotname` to name the Table of Contents and the related lists, so you have to redefine these macros.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks; apparently, I can accept in 4 minutes!